# Issue evaluating legacy Gradle project `org/gradle/listener/ActionBroadcast`

Tags: gradle

When working on a legacy project, I mysteriously started getting the following error message:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':gateway'.
>
> > org/gradle/listener/ActionBroadcast

This error message started occurring when I ran the command `gradle clean build`. Why am I getting this error message all of a sudden? Note that unlike other SO questions dealing with this error message, my problem should have nothing to do with a Sonarqube upgrade, as the project doesn't use Sonarqube.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that my project required Gradle 2.14, but I had accidentally switched my command prompt to Gradle 4.8. When I switched back to Gradle 2.14, this error message ceased.

Comment: I have faced the same issue . the project which i started configuring in local doesn't mention the gradle version. project uses the spring-boot-gradle for 1.4.0-RELEASE. my local has 4.10.3 gradle version.  Able to build from terminal not from intellij : `The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4.` https://www.reddit.com/r/IntelliJIDEA/comments/schypq/my_project_is_using_gradle_2141_but_intellij/?rdt=33582